# How can I make an HTTPS request in Squeak or Pharo?

Tags: web-services, smalltalk, squeak, pharo

How can I make an HTTPS request from Squeak or Pharo? `HTTPClient` and friends seem to lack any facilities for SSL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Zodiac](http://zdc.stfx.eu/) as mentioned above will enable you to make HTTPS requests from Zinc.

Enable it like this (recipe from the [Pharo forum](http://forum.world.st/Zinc-HTTPS-tt3755796.html)):

First download the [SqueakSSL](http://code.google.com/p/squeakssl/) plugin and put it in your Pharo directory, and then load the necessary packages:

```
"Load Zinc HTTP Components"
Gofer it 
  squeaksource: 'ZincHTTPComponents'; 
  package: 'Zinc-HTTP'; 
  package: 'Zinc-Tests'; 
  package: 'Zinc-Patch-HTTPSocket'; 
  load. 

"Load Zodiac including extras"
Gofer it 
  squeaksource: 'Zodiac'; 
  package: 'Zodiac-Core'; 
  package: 'Zodiac-Tests'; 
  load. 

"Load extra Zinc support for Zodiac"
Gofer it 
  squeaksource: 'ZincHTTPComponents'; 
  package: 'Zinc-Zodiac'; 
  load. 

"Switch to the Zn Zodiac socket factory" 
ZnNetworkingUtils default: ZnZodiacNetworkingUtils new.
```

And you should be able to make requests against HTTPS resources.

Comment: Finally! A pure Smalltalk solution to talking via HTTPS.  About time.

Answer (score 6):

You can use SqueakSSL easily through WebClient like so:

> WebClient httpGet:
>   'https://www.google.com/search?q=squeak'.

There may be a problem with certificates, in which case you will have to catch and ignore the errors ([see here](http://forum.world.st/WebClient-SqueakSSL-https-td2301818.html)).

Also, keep your eye on the [Zinc http framework](http://hudson.lukas-renggli.ch/job/Zinc/), which will be Pharo's new default soon.  It doesn't seem to have ssl yet, but it's being rapidly developed.

Answer (score 1):

[There was a bit of discussion on the mailing list.](http://forum.world.st/WebClient-with-SSL-td3026559.html) In short:

[SqueakSSL is supposed to do the job](http://squeakingalong.wordpress.com/2010/07/19/squeakssl-released/), but may need some fixing. [It can be invoked through WebClient](http://www.squeaksource.com/WebClient.html), as Sean Denigris noted:

```
WebClient httpGet: 'https://www.google.com/search?q=squeak'.
```

And, from the mailing list:

> [If you know whom you want to connect to, then you can use stunnel.](http://www.stunnel.org/)

Comment: Mmm interesting... wonder if stunnel supports wildcards... I think not. I think I need the native SSL connection from Pharo for when the SSL client connection is to a gateway with subdomains. Like when points to some account named in the subdomain of the url. Have to try that WebClient to https

Answer (score 0):

In a production environment we just use Lighttpd (or Apache) to translate from http to https

Comment: I'm not looking to *serve* HTTPS; in that case, I'd absolutely just stick an SSL terminator in front. I'm looking to *consume* it in a client application.

Comment: Have in mind that you should be able to do https -> http too. See here [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/227057/revers-proxy-http-https)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use stunnel.

Why?

To outsource completely the CPU intensive encryption/decryption tasks to a native library and free the VM of that stress at all.

In the other hand, you might want to keep an eye on [Zodiac](http://squeaksource.com/Zodiac) that started by [this initiative](http://forum.world.st/SSL-HTTPS-SecureSocketStream-SSLSession-for-Pharo-Squeak-and-other-Smalltalk-implementations-td3517404.html)

Answer (score 0):

In recent Pharo images the support is much better since Zinc and Zodiac are integrated.
Just evaluate

ZnEasy get: 'https://www.google.com'

for example.

A detailed docu can be found here:

http://www.pharo-project.org/news?dialog=documentation-for-zinc-http

For HTTPS client, Secure POP client, Secure SMTP client
read

http://zdc.stfx.eu/zodiac-paper.html